# Data from succesful betas: what to expect with questions/day

Tags: discussion

User "cheap effective diet pills" at Meta Stackoverflow provided me with this data about questions per day from succesful sites (2 that graduated and 2 that will). This should help us know what to expect.

Please consider asking good questions. If something comes up in your teaching or you remember problems you had in the past, see if you can make it into a great question.

**Workplace** graduated 2014-02-21

[image: Workplace]

**Money** graduated 2014-02-26

[image: money]

**Graphic Design** is [getting its own design](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/836).

[image: design]

**Academia** [will get one on 6-8 weeks](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/830/13142)

[image: academia]

Comment: What does our graph look like?

Comment: We've had 9 questions in 24 hours, so we haven't settled down to the '5 a day' level. Hopefully we won't!

Comment: Oh, these are plots from *public* beta! Gotcha. I'll keep posting questions to keep us up!

Comment: @brendansullivan07: Please note that artificially posting questions to make the site look active is not a good thing. Please post questions to get answers you are interested in, not to keep us up.

Comment: Yes yes of course. I didn't mean that was my intent.

Comment: @brendansullivan07 I didn't get that impression from you at all.

Comment: The viable range for the question volume varies a lot between topics, I'd advise against focusing too much on specific numbers here. There are some mininum values below which it gets really problematic, but if you have somewhat reasonable values here (at least ~3-5) question quality is typically the more important concern.

Comment: @BrianRushton: As of today, all the 'beta' stats look good except for the questions/day. Can you get your hands on a graph for the first 20 days of public beta (or 30 days of beta)?